# Use of undeclared identifier in Xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

I am trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField/) framework manually in my Xcode project. As I am structuring my project, I am adding it inside a folder [not a group]. So then the problem is started, "use of undeclared identifier **SkyFloatingLabelTextField**. What should I do to make it work properly?

I tried the same in sample project as well and the error is same.

I am not getting any options when trying drag and drop the folder to the project structure. The same when try adding through "Add Files".

Comment: is xcode 9.1 released ? it is working fine i have added this framework now .

Comment: How did you add it? Manually? I pointed to beta.

Comment: In sample, run **SkyFloatingLabelTextFieldObjectiveCExample.xcworkspace**  instead of **SkyFloatingLabelTextFieldObjectiveCExample.xcodeproj**

Comment: ok it i added manually,

Comment: @KarthikeyanBose, I am not checking the sample code, I want to add it in my project.

Comment: @KKRocks, Ok, please let me know if you are able to do it manually?

Comment: you are working ObjC or in Swift? In Swift its working fine for me. I just drag and drop the files from source and import SkyFloatingLabelTextField.
Using xcode 9.1

Comment: @Hemang why you want to add inside a folder not a group ? any specific reason ?

Comment: I am doing the same since years and it's a best practice for me. As when I come to the source code folder, I can see all the structure of my source. @iOSDev

Comment: There is no Xcode 9.1 at this time. Do you mean Xcode 9.0 beta 1?

Comment: @MatusalemMarques, corrected. It's 9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the Sources folder inside another folder at the workspace.

[image]

Added the folder using "Add Files to ..." option.

Checked the Target Membership for all the files inside Sources folder, as it was not checked.[image]

Although, it looks like source code of SkyFloatingLabelTextField, has not been updated for Swift4. You may need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, this doesn't help. I am still getting the same error. I have followed all the steps which you have suggested.

Comment: I was able to build my sample project successfully. Whats the issue?

Comment: The same issue. I am not sure what's wrong here. Would you check on my sample project? I can share the link if you want.

Comment: If you are still getting the unresolved error, you must check the Build Phases->Compile Source and check whether the SkyFloatingLabelTextField files are there or not. If they are there, clean your project, quit xcode and try building once again

Comment: Just tried in another sample project and it worked. :(!

Comment: Looks like a Derived data related issue to me, then. Open derived data folder, quit xcode, delete derived data, empty trash, open xcode and build the project. Change the order of exexution of these steps at your own peril:)

Comment: @Hemang you should use CocoaPods or Carthage to integrate instead, there's a know issue for CocoaPods where it doesn't correctly set the swift version of the project. Xcode 9 can compile both Swift 3 and 4. See this issue for a CocoaPods workaround https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField/issues/158

Answer (score 0):

Don't drag and drop file. You can add manually these files then its working fine.[image]

Comment: OP says in the question that it is also not working through `Add Files`

Comment: Can i see your issue, because its working fine on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens to me even if I installed SkyFloatingLabelTextField using CocoaPods. I only had to add

```
import SkyFloatingLabelTextField
```

in order to add the definition to my ViewController.